# How to add multiple columns in ListSelectionDialog in eclipse?

Tags: java, eclipse, dialog, jface, multiple-columns

I am creating a dialog by extending `org.eclipse.ui.dialogs.ListSelectionDialog`

While overriding `createDialogArea(Composite parent)` if I call `super.createDialogArea(parent)` and create 3 columns in the table viewer,
the **columnCount** of `org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Table` is set to `1` by default.
Hence, the *labelprovider's* `getText()` is called only for column with `index 0` and I don't get text in other 2 columns.

How can I create/add multiple columns in `createDialogArea(Composite parent)` so that it works correctly?

Answer (score 1):

Underlying table in `ListSelectionDialog` uses [`TableLayout`](http://help.eclipse.org/helios/topic/org.eclipse.platform.doc.isv/reference/api/org/eclipse/jface/viewers/TableLayout.html) and by default it is configured to span the first (and only) column to 100% of the table width. So, you you add more columns, you also need to configure the layout using `addColumnData(ColumnLayoutData data)` method.

Comment: You are wrong. You can't have a `TableViewerColumn` without an underlying `TableColumn`. `TableViewerColumn` either requires a `TableColumn` in its constructor or creates a new instance on its own.

Comment: @p12t You're right, thanks for pointing this out. I corrected my answer.